# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore deleted when app finishes running in dubugger/simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8.1, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have an iPad app (XCode 6.1, iOS 8.11) *that works just fine on the device*.  However,  each time I restart the app using the debugger *with* the simulator (8.1) the all of the contents of the store are empty from what was saved from the previous run.  When running using the simulator only (not connected to the debugger) the data is in the store.

Anybody else had this problem, or know why it's happening to my app?

Answer (score 1):

Key-value is not supported on the simulator, according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html) Apple doc.

Comment: This is an absolute bummer. This makes it a total pain in the you-know-what to test these things.